# Which base url should I use when I perform GET request with Axios in Heroku with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, mongoose, axios

I'm working with a MERN stack app. This app works perfectly when I run it locally , but I'm not sure why my Axios get request doesn't work in my React components when I run my app in Heroku.

In this bit of code, the Axios get call returns me a plain html object.

```
import { useState, useEffect} from "react";
const axios = require('axios').default;

function MyReactComponent() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get("/api/standings").then(response => {
            const myData = response.data

            console.log(myData);

            //logs a plain html object working in heroku
        });

    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, this is an example</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyReactComponent;
```

When I do it with promises it logs undefined:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const axios = require('axios').default;

function MyReactComponent() {

    useEffect(() => {

        const [data, setData] = useState([]);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios
                .get("/api/standings")
                .then(res => {
                    resolve(res.data)
                    console.log(resolve(res.data))

                    //logs undefined working in heroku
                }, err => reject(err));
        });
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, this is an example</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyReactComponent;
```

I've to point out that working locally I must use Proxy in the "package.json" in my front-end folder in order to make Axios perform the request without getting a 404 error:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
```

I know that if I put "/ANYTHINGELSE" when performing Axios call, the base URL is "https://appname.herokuapp.com". So What should I do?

Comment: did you try importing without ".default" ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried without ".default" and importing like " import axios from 'axios' ". Nothing changes

Comment: then if you're using proxy on localhost, you should initialize bearer token with axios as provided with [**this link**](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults) to not to get unauthorized response.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using bearer token in any part of my normal requests, so if I try to add that code to my JS file, token is not defined. I've tried to do what you are telling me looking to other posts but it doesn't work for me. I realy don't understand it, I've watched tons of videos of people doing the same as me, and they got no problem with getting data from their db with axios

Comment: well it was obvious not related to axios' itself but it's not possible to debug from outside of your repo and background

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it, it was not a Axios problem, even not a front-end problem.

In my back-end, the index.js file where my server is defined was something like this:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


//SETTINGS
app.use(cors());
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 4000);

.
. //ETC
.

//THEN, Defining what front-end should show if heroku is on production

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build')));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build/index.html'));
    })

//And then my server routes...

//ROUTES
app.use("/api/standings", require("./routes/standings"));
app.use("/api/races", require("./routes/races"));
app.use("/api/f1datas", require("./routes/f1datas"));


.
.//More code
.
```

This final part should be swapped

```
//ROUTES
app.use("/api/standings", require("./routes/standings"));
app.use("/api/races", require("./routes/races"));
app.use("/api/f1datas", require("./routes/f1datas"));

//THEN

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build')));
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../frontend/build/index.html'));
    })
```